# Is it possible to authenticate with an Azure Key Vault using a User Principle via a c# Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-keyvault

I can easily authenticate against an Azure KeyVault using an Enterprise Application, however this seems insecure in a deployed environment as I then need to store a ClientID and ClientSecret in the application itself, I'd prefer to have the user authenticate within the app using an AAD login then use that login to authenticate against the KeyVault to ensure that any users connecting are authorised.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is technically possible using `InteractiveBrowserCredential` of `Azure.Identity` SDK. However, by doing this you would need to give User/Group required permission (e.g. secret get etc.). So if you are fine with that, continue reading. Also, you would need to maintain only the TenantID and ClientID of an AAD application in your desktop application.

1. Create an AAD App of native client app type in your AAD tenant with reply URL "http://localhost". Note the Client ID of the app created, you would need this in code for user authentication.
   [image]
2. Add "Azure Key Vault" API delegated permission to the above created application and grant Admin consent.
   [image]
3. Give required Keyvault permissions (like Secret Get etc.) to your required AAD Users or Groups from Access Policy.
   [image]
4. Add nuget packages in your application: `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets` and `Azure.Identity`
5. Add the below code in the suitable place like Form load or something where you would need to do key vault operation (e.g. retrieving secrets etc.).

```
            // Create a new secret client using the Interactive credential from Azure.Identity 
            // This will prompt the user to login .
            var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri("https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/"), 
                credential: new InteractiveBrowserCredential("<tenant-id>", "<client-id>"));

            // Retrieve a secret using the secret client.
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("<secret-name>");
```

voilà, that's it. It will open a browser window to prompt user to login and continue with auth token from user principle.